# Append without for loop

Tags: python, loops, pandas

Consider

```
ID  EXPENDITURE
1   100 
1   101   
1   88   
2   28   
2   77
```

I wish to calculate the total expenditure by ID, that is:

```
 ID TOTAL_EXPENDITURE
 1  289
 2  105
```

My current code looks like this:

```
list = []
for i in df.ID.unique()
    CSPEC = df.loc[df['ID'] == i]
    TOTAL_EXP = CSPEC['EXPENDITURE'].sum()
    list.append(TOTAL_EXP)
```

This would indeed give me the answer. However, I am facing 117705 unique IDs and this for loop would take ages.

I have read about numpy, but after following a YouTube tutorial I am still not sure how to implement it; hence, I would prefer a different approach (if possible!) Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your example.

Comment: And then look into `df.groupby()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('ID')['EXPENDITURE'].sum()
```

Gets the expenditure sums for each ID. It's still fast because Pandas is built on numpy.